# Excel to JSON parser with http download

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I've been working on a project ([link](https://github.com/codingo/Ransomware-Resources/tree/master/UpdateJsonDataset)) to download a spreadsheet of known ransomware and properties and turn it into json so I can better consume the information within early detection projects.

I'm new to python - what can I be doing better? The destination json I'm converting can be found [here](https://github.com/codingo/Ransomware-Resources/blob/master/ransomware_overview.json).

**update_json.py** (entry point)

```
from excel_to_json import excel_to_json
from download_file import download_file

SOURCESHEET = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWS238xacAto-fLKh1n5uTsdijWdCEsGIM0Y0Hvmc5g/pub?output=xlsx'
OUTPUTSHEET = '../RansomwareOverview.xlsx'
JSONFILE = '../ransomware_overview.json'

def write_json_file(json_data, filename):
    output = open(filename, 'w')
    output.writelines(json_data)

def generate_json(source_file, download_destination, json_file):
    download_file(source_file, download_destination)
    write_json_file(excel_to_json(download_destination), json_file)

generate_json(SOURCESHEET, OUTPUTSHEET, JSONFILE)
```

**download_file.py**

```
import urllib.request

def download_file(source, destination):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(source, destination)
    except IOError:
        print('An error occured trying to write an updated spreadsheet. Do you already have it open?')
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        print('An error occured trying to download the file. Please check the source and try again.')
```

**excel_to_json.py**

```
import simplejson as json
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict

def excel_to_json(filename):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    mw = wb.sheet_by_index(2)

    # List to hold dictionaries
    c_list = []

    # Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict
    for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
        wares = OrderedDict()
        row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)

        if row_values[6]=="":
            name = row_values[0]
            gre=[name]
        elif "," in row_values[6]:
            e=row_values[6].split(",")
            ge = [row_values[0]]
            gre=e+ge
        else:
            gre=[row_values[0],row_values[6]]

        wares['name'] = gre
        wares['extensions'] = row_values[1]
        wares['extensionPattern'] = row_values[2]
        wares['ransomNoteFilenames'] = row_values[3]
        wares['comment'] = row_values[4]
        wares['encryptionAlgorithm'] = row_values[5]
        wares['decryptor'] = row_values[7]
        if row_values[8]=="":
            wares['resources'] = [row_values[9]]
        elif row_values[9]=="":
            wares['resources']=[row_values[8]]
        else:
            wares['resources'] = [row_values[8], row_values[9]]
        wares['screenshots'] = row_values[10]

        for r in range(1, mw.nrows):
            rowe = mw.row_values(r)

            if row_values[0] == rowe[0]:
                wares['microsoftDetectionName']=rowe[1]
                wares['microsoftInfo'] = rowe[2]
                wares['sandbox'] = rowe[3]
                wares['iocs'] = rowe[4]
                wares['snort'] = rowe[5]

        c_list.append(wares)

    # Serialize the list of dicts to JSON
    return json.dumps(c_list, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Performance tips:**

- [`ujson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) can bring more speed
- since both `simplejson` and `xlrd` are pure-python, you may get performance improvements "for free" by switching to [`PyPy`](http://pypy.org/)
- you may (or not) see speed and memory usage improvements if switching to [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html) and especially in the ["read-only" mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#read-only-mode)
- in the `excel_to_json` function, you are accessing the same values from `row_values` by index multiple times. Defining intermediate variables (e.g. defining `name = row_values[6]` and using `name` variable later on) and avoiding accessing an element by index more than once might have a positive impact
- I'm not sure I completely understand the inner `for r in range(1, mw.nrows)` loop. Can you `break` once you get the `if row_values[0] == rowe[0]` evaluated to `True`?
- are you sure you need the `OrderedDict` and cannot get away with a regular `dict`? (there is a [serious overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19643045/771848) for CPythons prior to 3.6)
- instead of `.dumps()` and a separate function to dump a JSON string to a file - use `.dump()` method to *dump to a file directly* - make sure to use `with` context manager when opening a file

**Code Style notes:**

- follow [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) in terms of whitespace usage in expressions and statements
- properly [organize imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)
- `if row_values[6]=="":` can be simplified to `if not row_values[6]:` (similar for some other if conditions later on)
- the `generate_json()` call should be put into the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid it being executed on import
- the `excel_to_json()` function is not quite easy to grasp - see if you can add a helpful docstring and/or comments to improve on clarity and readability

**Other notes:**

- improve variable naming. Variables like `sh`, `mw`, `rowe` are very close to being meaningless. I would also replace `wb` with a more explicit `workbook`
- have you considered using [`pandas.read_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) to read the contents into the dataframe and then dumping it via [`.to_json()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) (after applying the desired transformations)?

Comment: This is awesome, thank-you. Haven't come accross pypy / pep8 (new to python) until now so quite a lot to dig into!

Comment: Your remark about `OrderedDict` being slow is basically out-dated. In CPython 3.6 (and the corresponding PyPy version), `dict`s are insertion-ordered and `OrderedDict` is just a thin wrapper around them. So they are (almost) as fast as dicts now.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
>
>     if row_values[6]=="":
>         name = row_values[0]
>         gre=[name]
>     elif "," in row_values[6]:
>         e=row_values[6].split(",")
>         ge = [row_values[0]]
>         gre=e+ge
>     else:
>         gre=[row_values[0],row_values[6]]
>
>     wares['name'] = gre
>     wares['extensions'] = row_values[1]
>     wares['extensionPattern'] = row_values[2]
>     wares['ransomNoteFilenames'] = row_values[3]
>     wares['comment'] = row_values[4]
>     wares['encryptionAlgorithm'] = row_values[5]
>     wares['decryptor'] = row_values[7]
>     if row_values[8]=="":
>         wares['resources'] = [row_values[9]]
>     elif row_values[9]=="":
>         wares['resources']=[row_values[8]]
>     else:
>         wares['resources'] = [row_values[8], row_values[9]]
>     wares['screenshots'] = row_values[10]
> ```

This can be improved in many ways:

- Since you're going to use all 10 values of a row (some several times even), you can unpack the whole row at once and avoid several lookups later on:

  ```
  name, extensions, ext_pattern, filenames, comment, algorithm, name_extra, decryptor, resources_part_1, resources_part_2, screenshots = sh.row_values(rownum)
  ```

  However, if each row contains more than 10 columns, you'd have to account for that and discard extra ones using `*_`:

  ```
  (name, extensions, ext_pattern, filenames, comment,
   algorithm, name_extra, decryptor, resources_part_1,
   resources_part_2, screenshots, *_) = sh.row_values(rownum)
  ```
- `split` will always return a list with at least one element: the original string if the separator was not found.
- You can simplify the tests for the empty string by using `not` as the empty string evaluates to `False` in a boolean context.

All in all, you can write:

```
(name, extensions, ext_pattern, filenames, comment,
 algorithm, name_extra, decryptor, resources_part_1,
 resources_part_2, screenshots, *_) = sh.row_values(rownum)

wares = {
    'name': [name],
    'extensions': extensions,
    'extensionPattern': ext_pattern,
    'ransomNoteFilenames': filenames,
    'comment': comment,
    'encryptionAlgorithm': algorithm,
    'decryptor': decryptor,
    'screenshots': screenshots,
}
if name_extra:
    wares['name'].extend(name_extra.split(','))
if not resources_part_1:
    wares['resources'] = [resources_part_2]
elif not resources_part_2:
    wares['resources'] = [resources_part_1]
else:
    wares['resources'] = [resources_part_1, resources_part_2]
```

But the resource part feels ugly so I think I’d rather write it as a list-comprehension:

```
(name, extensions, ext_pattern, filenames, comment,
 algorithm, name_extra, decryptor, resources_part_1,
 resources_part_2, screenshots, *_) = sh.row_values(rownum)

wares = {
    'name': [name],
    'extensions': extensions,
    'extensionPattern': ext_pattern,
    'ransomNoteFilenames': filenames,
    'comment': comment,
    'encryptionAlgorithm': algorithm,
    'decryptor': decryptor,
    'screenshots': screenshots,
    'resources': [r for r in (resources_part_1, resources_part_2) if r]
}
if name_extra:
    wares['name'].extend(name_extra.split(','))
```

Comment: Thanks a heap! I'm working through a branch making this pep8 compliant at the moment but I'll circle back and review this after.